# Proxy use in VSE for 2.79

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Can anyone please advise on the method for using proxies in 2.79.. the usual method of choosing a desired proxy render size for playback .. after creating the proxy doesn't seem to work anymore as normal .. choosing 25% after making the proxy results in the video freezing after a few frames..

Any help with regard to this would be most appreciated .. cheers..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe having the same issue.

I'm new to VSE so I tried different setting in the proxy panel (resolution, timecode) and Proxy playback still not working.

Checked the Proxy footages generated by Blender and it look ok when playing on VLC.

Then tried with **Blender2.78c** on Mac OS10.9 which work normally.

Hope it would help.

---

*Update 2017.11.05*

Tried the Latest Build **blender-2.79.0-01a3c95609** from https://builder.blender.org/download/ .
Import movie to VSE, and create proxy. Just work normally. The playback problem seems fixed.

Comment: yes i have reverted to 2.78C also .. and i have no problems at all .. everything works as normal .. i just think it must be broken in 2.79 .. but sadly i wasnt able to glean any further technical information about how it works in the latest version  from anyone who might actually know ..

Answer (score 0):

Same here. I managed to get it working with a short clip by doing the following things:

1) import the video
2) create the proxy and make sure you choose overwrite and record run
3) remove the video from the session
4) import it again

Unfortunately, this seems to work only for short movies.